# ImportError while python package installation

Tags: python, django, importerror, html5lib, django-wiki

I'm installing django-wiki exactly as shown in the docs http://django-wiki.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

When I try to perform 'python manage.py migrate', I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                  
File "manage.py", line 13, in <module>                                                                            
  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)                                                                             
File "/var/www/unihotel/common_apps_1/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line 
  utility.execute()                                                                                               
File "/var/www/unihotel/common_apps_1/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute                   
  django.setup()                                                                                                  
File "/var/www/unihotel/common_apps_1/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup                                      
  apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)                                                                          
File "/var/www/unihotel/common_apps_1/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate                             
  app_config.import_models(all_models)                                                                            
File "/var/www/unihotel/common_apps_1/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models                          
  self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)                                                          
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module                                      
  __import__(name)                                                                                                
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wiki/models/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>                             
  from .article import *  # noqa                                                                                  
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wiki/models/article.py", line 14, in <module>                              
  from wiki.conf import settings                                                                                  
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wiki/conf/settings.py", line 3, in <module>                                
  import bleach                                                                                                   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bleach/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>                                  
  from .sanitizer import BleachSanitizer                                                                          
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bleach/sanitizer.py", line 5, in <module>                                  
  from html5lib.constants import tokenTypes                                                                       
ImportError: cannot import name tokenTypes
```

But when I import it with the python shell...

```
>>> from html5lib.constants import tokenTypes
>>> print(tokenTypes)
{u'Comment': 6, u'StartTag': 3, u'EmptyTag': 5, u'Characters': 1, u'EndTag': 4, u'ParseError': 7, u'Doctype': 0, u'SpaceCharacters': 2}
```

...it works just fine.

Please, any help on this would be useful!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `manage.py` was using other version of `html5lib` than the python interpreter. The easiest way to detect this is to go straight to the package file that caused the error, and print out the package version using `app.__version__`. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: You can use `python manage.py shell` to get the same python shell as Django.